# Adding Bootstrap RTL LESS to Magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, less, static-content, ui-library

I need to include [bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl/tree/master/less) LESS files to my theme when using fa_IR locale.

**So I did:**

1. Add those downloaded LESS files to: `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme_Name>/web/i18n/fa_IR/css/source/bootstrap-rtl`.
2. Import the main LESS file (bootstrap-rtl.less) in _extend.less at same directory above: `@import 'bootstrap-rtl/bootstrap-rtl.less'`
3. Because this **bootstrap-rtl** package need **bootstrap variable** I copied **bootstrap** LESS file in same directory above, and changed import line:8 in `bootstrap-rtl.less` to : `@import "../bootstrap/_variables.less"`. So now it can access to bootstrap variable.

**The Problem Is:**

when using this command to deploy static contents:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It will return some error (58 Error) like this:

```
variable @grid-float-breakpoint is undefined in file C:/xampp7/htdocs/Magento_2.1.9/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme_Name>/fa_IR/css/source/bootstrap-rtl/type-rtl.less ...
```

and these styles **will not compile** at the end.

**You Should Know:**

- My theme inherits from another theme that using bootstrap as External UI Library source, So is there any conflict in `bootstrap` styles with my theme and it's parent theme?
- I'm using **Magento 2.1.9** with **PHP 7.0.22** and **XAMPP 3.2.2**.

Thanks in advance.